Different results for different Docker commands
I'm trying to check whether docker-compose is present using the approach described here.
Seeing the following output when executing:
$ docker compose version
Docker Compose version v2.12.0

however the following command results in a different version:
$ docker-compose --version
docker-compose version 1.29.2, build 5becea4c

Is this the expected behavior and/or how to explain the discrepancy?
As Wesley pointed out, looks like there was a transition on Docker tooling side and the docker compose command is the way forward now.

docker-compose is calling Compose V1, an older external binary.
docker compose calls upon Compose V2, that is now built-in.
Compose was rewritten and integrated into docker.
Technically, it's a Docker plugin now.
In this case, both Compose V1, and an up to date version of Docker are on the machine.

Interesting tidbit about the version upgrade.  Wondering how they both ended up on the machine, as far as I recall only Desktop was originally installed (in 2022) unless somehow docker was installed as part of WSL2 subsystem as a package upgrade.
